# Android - How to catch specific exceptions , change their messages, but leave other types of exception with their original messages

Tags: java, android, exception

I'm trying to catch all exceptions from these types when sending data over the Internet :

- java.net.SocketException
- java.io.EOFException

Whenever one of theses exceptions ocurrs I want to show a message like "Unable to send data. Please retry later" instead of their original messages.But if the exception is from other type I want to keep the original message.

I have tried something like this in a functions that returns an Object type

```
    try {
         //send data, return data 
    }       
    catch( IOException ioe){
        return ioe;
    }   
    catch (Exception e) {
        return e;
    }
```

and when I'm finally  going to show a toast I do something like :

```
        if (requestObject instanceof String) {
            //everything went alright

        } 
        else if( requestObject instanceof IOException){
            Toast.makeText(this, "Unable to send data. Please retry later", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);            
        }
        else if (requestObject instanceof Exception) {  
            Toast.makeText(this, ((Exception) requestObject).getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);         
        }
```

I might be trying with the wrong type of exceptions because the toast keeps on displaying the original message.

I really appreciate if you could help me with this, I have tried other solutions too but with no luck.

Comment: What is showing in Toast

Comment: Fist of all , will IOException handle both java.net.SocketException and java.io.EOFException ?? Because somehow I got the message that those exceptions usually show :S